# How to get rid of these seams on the lightmap? ( Unity )

Tags: unity, textures, rendering, uv-mapping, lightmap

The wall is made of blocks of identical wall models with the same UVs. How to get rid of these seams on the lightmap?

[image]
[image]
[image]

How I made this scene with this models:

1. I made 3D model of the wall element in Blender.
2. Import the wall element in Unity and generate UVs in FBX settings.
3. I made walls from the wall element in the Scene and marked all wall elemets as Contribute GI.
4. Next I baked lightMap and get this seams.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? What exact steps would a user need to follow to make a mesh and a scene that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @DMGregory I added step info as you asked.

Comment: Images should be embedded, not linked externally, and you should include the steps of how to create a model that exhibits this problem. Do not assume that it is universal to any model made in Blender.